# Core Data doesn't save the first time

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a problem with RestKit 0.22 and Core Data for saving. To be sure that the rest of my project doesn't cause the problem, I reproduce it with RKTwitterCoreData in RestKit examples. I simply remove seeding part to start with an empty sqlite database. My app is based on the same concept.

My problem happens the first time I run the app. The app receives the data from twitter and displays it. But if I look at the sqlite database itself, it's empty. When I start the app the second time, the database is filling.

Is it possible for RestKit to save the data at the moment it receives it?

Is it possible that RestKit cache all data before saving them. I though that my problem happened because managedObjectCache in `RKManagedObjectStore` is set with `RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache` but I also tried with `RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache` and I got the same result.

I also tried to save manually in the success bloc with `[[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] persistentStoreManagedObjectContext] save:nil]` and that didn't work.

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking at the sqlite database whilst the app is still running from Xcode?  If so, from experience you will need to stop the app running before looking at the data.

Comment: I tried both, when it's run and after I stop the app.

Comment: Which sqlite file are you looking at and how (not that you should look at any of the files directly...)

Answer (score 1):

RestKit does save the mapping result automatically, and before calling the success completion block.

If you want to check what is in the store, ask the MOC (main thread or persistent store MOC) and check the `registeredObjects` / run a fetch request.

You should not look at the SQLite file(s). The table structure is a private implementation detail, and if you load the file at the command line with the wrong options you won't necessarily see what you expect.

Comment: We use Core Data Editor (available in the App Store) to look at the data store.

Comment: If I fetch data after success bloc I got all my datas in result. But the database is empty. To get access to the database I run it in the simulator and look in the app folder for the sqlite file or I use a software to get access to the device content. I open sqlite files with MesaSQLite. The first time I run the app the database is always empty.

Comment: So the seconds time you run the app, before doing anything else, you run a fetch - what does it return?

Comment: The second time if I fetch data just after setting the managedObjectStore I got all data and my database is full. Everything done before calling web service. With RKTwitterCoreData the database is filled after this line `NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error]` the second time I run the app.

Comment: So you have no problem and however you're loading the SQLite file outside the app is wrong (hence you see an empty store)

Comment: Is it possible to force RestKit to save data in database without "rebooting" the app?

Comment: It happens automatically, there is no need to force - indeed, you can't ask it not to save...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51685/discussion-between-olivierplante-and-wain)